# Does the total sound intensity increase when reflected?

Tags: acoustics, reflection, interference, superposition

In a closed pipe and sound it produced at one end of the tube and the other reflected the sound. If you measure the intensity within the pipe would it be greater than if there would be no reflection at all.

Comment: Sound is also reflected at open ends.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where in the pipe you measure and what the exact termination of the pipe is.

Most terminations (open, closed, something in between) will create a reflection which will lead to a standing wave in the pipe. The standing wave will have maxima and minima along the pipe so the intensity will vary up and down as you move the microphone along the pipe.

The only termination that doesn't produce a reflection would be 100% absorption (e.g. by using gradually increasing amounts of "fluff" along the pipe). In this case the intensity is constant.